# Почему выдается предупреждение [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Скрипт работает, но я получаю предупреждение. Не пойму, что делаю не так.

```
function loadCont() {

   let jqXHR = $.ajax({
      url: //url
      dataType: 'html'
   })

   jqXHR.done(function(html) {
      elem.html(html)
      loadCont_2()
   })
}

function loadCont_2() {
   let jqXHR = $.ajax({
      url: //url
      dataType: 'html'
   })

   jqXHR.done(function(html) {
      elem2.html(html)
   })
}
```

Comment: Вы про голый js говорите? В jQuery параметр async по умолчанию true

Comment: Но ведь тогда запросы синхронные станут. Впрочем, я попробовал, это не помогло

Comment: Я не очень дружу с инглишом, поэтому обратился сюда, на русскоязычную ветку сервиса

Comment: @And насколько я понимаю, если поставить параметр `async: false`, то запросы станут **синхронными**.

Comment: Приведенный код не может дать указанное предупреждение - скорее всего проблема в другом месте.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать запросы в таком формате:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "",
    dataType: 'html'
    success: function (html) {
         elem.html(html)
         loadCont_2()
        },
     error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        }
     });
```